# The combination of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3, \eta_4$ are four i.i.d random variables with $\eta_i$ ~ $N(0, 1)$. Then how to compute the probability density function (or characteristic function) of $$\frac{{(\eta_1 \eta_2 + \eta_3 \eta_4)}^2}{\eta_2^2 + \eta_4^2}.$$

Answer (score 5):

For every $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$, $a\eta_1+b\eta_3$ is centered normal with variance $a^2+b^2$ hence $$\frac{a\eta_1+b\eta_3}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ is standard normal. Thus, by independence, conditionally on $(\eta_2,\eta_4)$, $$\frac{\eta_1 \eta_2 + \eta_3 \eta_4}{\sqrt{\eta_2^2 + \eta_4^2}}$$ is standard normal, hence, unconditionally, $$\frac{\eta_1 \eta_2 + \eta_3 \eta_4}{\sqrt{\eta_2^2 + \eta_4^2}}$$ is standard normal. Finally, $$\xi=\frac{(\eta_1 \eta_2 + \eta_3 \eta_4)^2}{\eta_2^2 + \eta_4^2}$$ is distributed like $\eta^2$, where $\eta$ is standard normal. The PDF $f_\xi$ of $\xi$ follows, by the change of variable $y\to x=y^2$, as $$f_\xi(x)=\frac{e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\mathbf 1_{x>0}$$

Comment: +1 Wow! and that's the elegant way of solving the problem.